# inconsistent selection filter behavior with brush vs select (click)

Tags: vega-lite

I have the same spec for the charts below, except for the selection

[image]

[image]

One with brush selection ([editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-JAq3V19PZ8h54vY6vIBut4uAI6+ObMIJUa+wKLwADWLSUrDEYhHlA3CEOg8DMCe1T1I0272iihy9iCkBiOg65OC07RWoGkAYLoP6mOwKRlHy-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-mInmBnzYA8wbdTXdwt3iV7aU+1BZvi6xoPIFuTdIocCGHEAA), and one with click selection ([editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckALKNN6WGADiyJcl3o8yTWABqjWK3QSAXi7GYNwAZmBWeOihzqjIYGbocty6APrwLjQpAJ6pmt54+uysRspqGpCRmDigEBCQFH6sOthgANoadWC1XXXmSSnpmdQ5rZAAgtT68KxieKy68QBkYAByLgt+YABKOtwL8C3qvX3w+0p4rQCMAAzHJ1DeqdxUuhSMyADurYXNnXUAX3uXWA-WSaQyrhGumyY3GujwsDUUDOrAurQAHKpHrBnq93l8frpmkD-hAeicwYNIVkYWMAEI8MTcajZMArAAyjFC8QAyvAPkpDuUHijzpccFdpMDepAni8nATvjhfsgyWBSSdQYlwUMoaNTPTWLBGI5YEjsZBUejJQBmS3y-EfZVgVWa3oU2U66nDA1QADC3FQqDRjEhxhsKwAUvtdEo-N5UCKHlbxa1per6o7Fc6iX8Tu6QZmoN6Ib66aZA6hCCUnJGEi4BEF4Bbi6m0RKwFcrjKunLcQq3rmVcS1QXe90qWX9RWoABRTSscNlS3WztXABsDoHTsJI5JE+1A2ntNhpjnSiYjicpuoyPbNrAACYAJzbvE5veu0eFupH3U0tCZ5QAAEsgfgsPea7XE+76DkqebIL+5JtqWeqnmMIGsBgSjMB89ZcuwThbPCiLJpS0GSgArBOWY7p+LqquqyHdKhx7oUBYwAJJKIusCFIwJEIvWgZKD4cS6GAvI5ocraig+nYAOy0TiH5Dl+THjuq-4+jOwGQDxri6PkCAGBI8Z0quaaSnBu6MT+h5sQB5b6Ry6CfOyYAAAocBI8DedwfmwipCmtDRbbZup9n5r0LE6SenGmF5iDZCaGRiFJAoOLJUHWV2dyqfBw7fge2lObpGFJbA2RIIFLJsisvLcAKWwAOopAA1uRsqUWAb4RfRUWIcxh5ThxfqQE1LUZfygrClZHatG+hV2YhAL-AAuho7qQNl3D5JerSepAAAeR2QKEHxiJoYxoYBoyWng2SEMgYwpAdfiQL+kDAaCl3INdYzQY9z2vaYACOvgXMwQRUPe-HoPAXU4EosxiN93CEIjzC-Q0TRg2ANx0FR60QDtYjoNkTitB0RaUhgujI1A7DoLo3X1HtB13jUbZnMybM86K9T-YDpiRQhKn1E9L1jEoQamp9ktQAgfgE6CziXgTbSQAAxDcNy2nOG70veOsvgAYvStr+hikAbZamhBugpo06EfiwMg2KqhtLF9mINAODdKNo8WpOxROkAe-78ClCYrHyf43BBkdxZS6DYymkZjRiOzsrsKaQfK+lRyp1AhToGJFOuGMbSoPsHuO58ShtAAhMgVAXHQsCINyeAANLINk9tgJ8BfcJ8WB18ayCsIQG1gAAfCPY8T1PHt11QLe532ifJ6YnwoADW+hyFUfIDH53SwTkAhnMjD3pzt5Ijg2tncPu3Vk9svKK9YddH-GoZSenqAzJmkAWZswjuXMSoQUhJhfn9RgcxqY1EjgDc+scxhnwvgCAE9t1S7SFPtW8Kd5J8xSKQoWF0rqF37GpCWpdIBX2-qgBWOclaR2LudDW1Ata61CJoDEmhbTwFNgI9AyANzsDtg7J2LsX5uzEB7L2o4fYcP9rw3irRUZiDEKHZi-ww74PqIsRQYg4aoJVv7c65CBaPF4sgF6Dj0S4JAACIAA))

As you can see, one has the orange and one has the blue---I only intend the orange colors to be used within a selection (e.g., a brush or a click). The second chart (with click) does what I wish, but the first (with brush) does not.

I'm not sure why selection vs. brush would have caused this difference.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that your click selection specifies `"empty": "none"`, while your brush selection does not.

- `"empty": "none"` indicates that an empty selection should be treated as if it contains none of the points.
- `"empty": "all"` (the default) indicates that an empty selection should be treated as if it contains all of the points.

Add `"empty": "none"` to your brush selection, it will have the same behavior as your click selection. See [Common Selection Properties](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html#common-selection-properties) in the docs for more details.